# Display variable name instead of value

Tags: variable

Is there a way to display the variable name instead of its value? for example, I need something like`varname = 1; function[varname];` and the output is `varname` instead of `1`

Comment: Have you looked into `HoldForm`? There are many threads on `Hold`ing around, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
varname = 1;

SetAttributes[ShowName, HoldAll]

ShowName[name_] :=
 Row[{"The name is ", HoldForm @ varname, " and its value is ", ReleaseHold @ varname}]

ShowName @ varname
```

> The name is varname and its value is 1

Or simply

```
HoldForm @ varname
```

> varname

Comment: Why not just say `ShowName = HoldForm`?

Answer (score 7):

There's also `Defer` to accomplish this:

```
varname = 1;

Defer @ varname
```

> varname