# Printing names of indexed variables instead of values

Tags: output-formatting, hold, variable

I'd like to display only the variable ([indexed variable](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)) name (in symbol form, not in string form) instead of its value in *Mathematica*. Say I have a variable `foo[i]` with `i` being the index, How do I get something like `{foo[1], foo[2]}` as output?

I have tried `i = 1; HoldForm[foo[i]]` but *Mathematica* seems to hold all evaluations, including replacing the index `i` with its value. `HoldForm[foo[i]] /. i -> i` also won't work.

There exists another thread in SE that connects with this question, but it doesn't seem to work either.

[Display variable name instead of value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/display-variable-name-instead-of-value)

Comment: `HoldForm[foo[i]] /. i -> 1` or `HoldForm[foo[i]] /. i -> j` will work.

Comment: Also `With[{i=1},HoldForm[foo[i]]]` works. As does `i=1;With[{i=i},HoldForm[foo[i]]]`.

Comment: Related: "[Elegant manipulation of the variables list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/280)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're seeking:

```
HoldForm[foo] /@ Range[2]
```

and if you want individual elements:

```
(HoldForm[foo] /@ Range[2])[[1]]
```

and

```
(HoldForm[foo] /@ Range[2])[[2]]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes this is working, but what if I want to extract the elements in the list? `HoldForm[foo] /@ {i}[[1]]` won't work.

Comment: Well I also discovered `HoldForm[foo]@i` :)