# How to return a variable name and value from within a self-contained function block?

Tags: function-construction, scoping, hold, variable

**Abstract:** I have viewed other solutions on StackExchange but none actually address using a fully self-contained function to return name and value of a variable. The only function that works requires using `SetAttributes[...]` outside the function before using it: [Display variable name instead of value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/display-variable-name-instead-of-value)

**Goal:** to create a completely self-contained function `Block[...]` or `Module[...]` that returns variable name and value without requiring using an outside function such as `SetAttributes[...]`.

**About the Code:** Below is the code for four different attempts. The top two are globally scoped and work fine. Bottom two are written into a function block but do not work. The output is decorated with strings to give you an idea of how I intend to use it.

```
varname=123;

(* this works *)
Row[{"Global Scope Defer: ","the name is ",Defer@varname," and value is -> ",varname}]

(*this works *)
SetAttributes[ShowName,HoldAll];
ShowName[name_]:=Row[{"Global Scope SetAttributes HoldForm: ","the name is ",HoldForm@name," and value is -> ",ReleaseHold@name}];
ShowName[varname]

(* this doesn't work *)
showDeferFunction[var_]:=Block[{pre,arrow},
pre="the name is ";
arrow=" and value is -> ";
Row[{"Functional Scoping Defer: ",pre,Defer@var,arrow,var}]
];
showDeferFunction[varname]

(* this doesn't work either *)
showHoldFormFunction[var_]:=Block[{pre,arrow},
pre="the name is ";
arrow=" and value is -> ";
SetAttributes[ShowName,HoldAll];
ShowName[name_]:=Row[{"Functional Scoping SetAttributes HoldForm: "pre,HoldForm@name,arrow,ReleaseHold@name}];
ShowName[var]
];
showHoldFormFunction[varname]
```

**The Output:**

```
Global Scope Defer: the name is varname and value is -> 123
Global Scope SetAttributes HoldForm: the name is varname and value is -> 123
Functional Scoping Defer: the name is 123 and value is -> 123
Functional Scoping SetAttributes HoldForm: the name is 123 and value is -> 123
```

Comment: Something like `xxx = 1; Function[Null, Row[{Defer[#1], " = ", #1}], {HoldAll}][xxx]`?

Comment: @J.M. thank you that is close but I am looking for a named function that would look something like below (example doesn't work) so i could re-use it without having to copy the function body each time: `fn[var_] := 
  Function[Null, Row[{Defer[#1], " = ", #1}], {HoldAll}][var];`

Comment: You don't need `var`; `fn = Function[(* stuff *)]` suffices.